# Pop up div region to opening halfway down the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using some code I got online awhile back that on clicking a link opens a blanket div that blacks out the page below and opens a small popup window in which I have a YouTube video.

It works fine but it places the popup in the center of the page vertically, which means that you have to scroll down to see the popup. How can I have the popup open close to the top all the time rather than halfway?

I've tried to put it together in a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xdH7k/3/

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to adjust the postion of the popup? I'm not sure if its the CSS thats doing it or Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xdH7k/6/embedded/result/

You need to change the declaration `popUpDiv.style.top`. I've set it to 10px in the demo here, rather than the `<div>` height

Comment: Thank you, I've marked this one correct as it was great you took the time to edit the fiddle. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out JQuery & JQuery UI. JQuery UI has a modal dialog popup that centers itself vertically and horizontally in the viewable area of the screen.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Thanks for this. I will use that next time. For this page I can get by with the hardcoded solution but that'll be good for next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this line:

```
popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-150;//150 is half popup's height
```

To something like:

```
popUpDiv_height=20;//150 is half popup's height
```

This removes vertically centering the div from the top and spaces it off just 20 pixels from the top.

Comment: Thanks this is correct, I've set it to 100 and it works just as I'd hoped.